# After performing feature selection in weka .How to save the new dataset to use it in other applications?

Tags: weka, feature-selection

How to save the new data set to use it in other applications after performing feature selection in WEKA?

Answer (score 0):

Simply export it in a format such as CSV, JSON, or .arff. In the Weka Explorer, there is a button labeled "Save..." in the top right of the GUI.

Comment: Thank you so much for your replay.I already saved the data set in the same way by using save button but there no difference on the data set .I actaully need to save only the reduced features after performing feature selection technique.Thanks in advanced

Comment: I performed Numeric to Nominal on my target variable in the older dataset and saved it. When I loaded the saved dataset, the variable was sitll numeric.